# Send messages to queues in JBoss 6 through Admin Console

Tags: java, jboss, queue, jms

Is it possible to send messages to JBoss 6 through Admin Console? There are only remove/expire/move/send to dead letter channel/pause/reset and so on operations in control tab but nothing about sending message manually. Also jms:queue is used if matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view them - but you cannot manually send them, a consumer will pick them off the queue when a consumer becomes available. Logically it would be too difficult to manually send them just because messages can be of types text, bytes and an object.  Text would be fairly easy but the rest would get progressively more difficult.  I may have misunderstood your manual sending however, e.g. did you want to create and send or just trigger a send.  Surely though you could write your own functionality and drop it into the JBoss Admin Console to manually send those specific types of messages though.

Comment: I want to send custom message manually but not just trigger sending. Jboss uses embedded Hornetq. I used admin console in Activemq and it was possible to send any message manually. So I would like to do something similar with Hornetq in Jboss

Comment: The latest JBoss, not sure if JBoss 6 had it but JBoss 7 now uses Apache ActiveMQ Artemis, ActiveMQ's integrating the HornetQ code base after it was donated by Red Hat.  Googling around, I'm not seeing the ability - sorry.  Hopefully I am wrong!

Comment: You're welcome Mikita!  If no one else answers, or you dont find a better answer and answer your own question - feel free to accept the answer though I know its not the greatest.